# Power Automate - Create new excel file with the contents of another

Tags: power-automate

I want to create a flow that triggers when I receive an email with an attachment.
The file received is an Excel in .xls format.

I need to:
Copy that file to a OneDrive business folder.
Create a new file, in .xlsx format, with the contents of the previous file.
Delete initial file.

Can you help me? The initial .xls file format is giving me headaches.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Basically PowerBI can't automatically refresh files in the .xls format that are stored on the OneDrive for business. And I haven't found a way to convert them